# How to extract hyperlinks from HWPFDocument provided a 2003 format word doc

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to extract hyperlinks from HWPFDocument but not able to find any clear API to do so. In XWPFDocument the API are clear like xwPFDocument.getHyperlinks() but in HWPFDocument i couldn't find any such API. PFB the code below of what i am trying to do

```
WordExtractor wordExtractor = null;
          
if(inFilePath == null || inFilePath.equals("")) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid file path");
}
HWPFDocument document = null;
InputStream is;
File file = new File(inFilePath);
is = new FileInputStream(file);

document = new HWPFDocument(is);

wordExtractor = new WordExtractor(document);`
```

I need to extract hyperlinks from the document object. Please help me out in this regard.

I tried to check if there are any direct APIs to extract hyperlinks but i could not find one in HWPFDocument object

Answer (score 0):

The `H` in all the Apache POI implementations of the binary Microsoft Office file systems (`HSSF`, `HSLF`, `HWPF`, ...) means horrible. And the `H`orrible `W`ord `P`rocessing `F`ormat is definiitely the most horrible of all the horrible formats.

Therefore the `HWPF` is in scratchpad state from begin on and has never left that state.

But the `WordExtractor` extracts hyperlinks out of `HWPFDocument`, at least if texts are linked and for the main body. Of course there is not much accessibility to those links while extracting.

The `WordToTextConverter` provides more access when one overrides it's `protected void processHyperlink` method.

Example for both:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocumentCore;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter.WordToTextConverter;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter.TextDocumentFacade;

public class ReadWordHWPFWordExtractor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordDocument.doc"));
  String content;
  
  WordExtractor wordExtractor = new WordExtractor(document);
  content = wordExtractor.getText();
  System.out.println(content);
  
  TextDocumentFacade textDocumentFacade = new TextDocumentFacade(org.apache.poi.util.XMLHelper.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument());  
  WordToTextConverter wordToTextConverter = new WordToTextConverter(textDocumentFacade) {
   @Override
   protected void processHyperlink(HWPFDocumentCore wordDocument, org.w3c.dom.Element currentBlock, Range textRange, int currentTableLevel, java.lang.String hyperlink) {
    // here you have access to hyperlink fields
    //System.out.println(textRange.getClass().getName()); //org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.FieldImpl 
    //System.out.println(textRange.text() + " -> " + hyperlink);
    processCharacters( wordDocument, currentTableLevel, textRange, currentBlock );
    currentBlock.appendChild(textDocumentFacade.createText("( -> " + hyperlink + ")"));
   }
  };
  
  wordToTextConverter.processDocument(document);
  content = wordToTextConverter.getText();
  System.out.println(content);
  
 }
}
```

Internally the hyperlinks are fields in the text body. `HWPFDocument` provides a method to get all such fields. Fields of type `FIELD_HYPERLINK` = 88, are hyperlinks. Such fileds consists of two subranges. The first subrange contains the link and the second subrange contains the linked text.

So, if the need is simply to get all links, one could get all fields and then filter out the fields of type `FIELD_HYPERLINK`.

Unfortunately the methods `Field.firstSubrange` and `Field.secondSubrange` seems to work only properly for the main range. When used for header range, footnote range or other ranges, it gets the correct range start and end in parent range but gets the wrong text, which seems to be from overall range instead of given parent range.

Following code shows gettimg the fields and provides methods to correct get the first subrange and second subrange.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.*;

public class ReadWordHWPFDocumentFields {
    
 private static final int FIELD_PAGE_REFERENCE = 37;
 private static final int FIELD_EMBEDDED_OBJECT = 58;
 private static final int FIELD_DROP_DOWN = 83;
 private static final int FIELD_HYPERLINK = 88; 
    
 static Range firstSubrange(Field field, Range parent, HWPFDocument document){
  if ( field.hasSeparator() ) {
   if ( field.getMarkStartOffset() + 1 == field.getMarkSeparatorOffset() ) return null;
   return new Range( parent.getStartOffset() + field.getMarkStartOffset() + 1, parent.getStartOffset() + field.getMarkSeparatorOffset(), document ) {
           @Override
           public String toString() {
            return "FieldSubrange1 (" + super.toString() + ")";
           }
          };
  }
  
  if ( field.getMarkStartOffset() + 1 == field.getMarkEndOffset() ) return null;
   
  return new Range( parent.getStartOffset() + field.getMarkStartOffset() + 1, parent.getStartOffset() + field.getMarkEndOffset(), document ) {
          @Override
          public String toString() {
           return "FieldSubrange1 (" + super.toString() + ")";
          }
         };  
 }
 
 static Range secondSubrange(Field field, Range parent, HWPFDocument document){
  if ( !field.hasSeparator() || field.getMarkSeparatorOffset() + 1 == field.getMarkEndOffset() ) return null;

  return new Range( parent.getStartOffset()+field.getMarkSeparatorOffset() + 1, parent.getStartOffset()+field.getMarkEndOffset(), document ) {
          @Override
          public String toString() {
           return "FieldSubrange2 (" + super.toString() + ")";
          }
         };
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordDocument.doc"));

  Fields fields = document.getFields();
  
  Range range = document.getRange();
  for (Field field : fields.getFields(FieldsDocumentPart.MAIN)) {
   System.out.println(field);  
   if (field.getType() == FIELD_HYPERLINK) {
    // System.out.println(field.firstSubrange(range));  
    // System.out.println(field.firstSubrange(range).text());  
    // System.out.println(field.secondSubrange(range));  
    // System.out.println(field.secondSubrange(range).text());
    
    String link = field.firstSubrange(range).text();  
    String text = field.secondSubrange(range).text();  
    System.out.println(text + " -> " + link);  
   }
  }

  range = document.getHeaderStoryRange();
  for (Field field : fields.getFields(FieldsDocumentPart.HEADER)) {
   System.out.println(field);  
   if (field.getType() == FIELD_HYPERLINK) {
    // System.out.println(field.firstSubrange(range)); // correct range start and end in parent range
    // System.out.println(field.firstSubrange(range).text()); // but wrong text, seems from overall range instead of given parent
    // System.out.println(field.secondSubrange(range));  // correct range start and end in parent range
    // System.out.println(field.secondSubrange(range).text()); // but wrong text, seems from overall range instead of given parent
   
    String link = firstSubrange(field, range, document).text();  
    String text = secondSubrange(field, range, document).text();  
    System.out.println(text + " -> " + link);  
   }
  }
  
  range = document.getFootnoteRange();
  for (Field field : fields.getFields(FieldsDocumentPart.FOOTNOTES)) {
   System.out.println(field);  
   if (field.getType() == FIELD_HYPERLINK) {   
    String link = firstSubrange(field, range, document).text();  
    String text = secondSubrange(field, range, document).text();  
    System.out.println(text + " -> " + link);  
   }
  }
  
  //range = document.getEndnoteRange();
  //for (Field field : fields.getFields(FieldsDocumentPart.ENDNOTES)) {
  //...
      
  range = document.getCommentsRange();
  for (Field field : fields.getFields(FieldsDocumentPart.ANNOTATIONS)) {
   System.out.println(field);  
   if (field.getType() == FIELD_HYPERLINK) {   
    String link = firstSubrange(field, range, document).text();  
    String text = secondSubrange(field, range, document).text();  
    System.out.println(text + " -> " + link);  
   }
  }
      
  //range = document.getMainTextboxRange();
  //for (Field field : fields.getFields(FieldsDocumentPart.TEXTBOX)) {
  //...
      
      
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response again axel